# pdftotext.exe problems with non-ASCII characters in file path

Tags: encoding, path, pdftotext

I'm using pdftotext.exe (https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html) to save text from pdf into txt file and came accross a problem with file path i.e. when there are non-ASCII characters in the path, the application can't create the txt file and can't open it.

`pdftotext.exe D:\Folder\File.pdf` - works fine.

`pdftotext.exe D:\Fołder\File.pdf` - produces error couldn't open file 'D:\Fo <c5<82>der\File.pdf'

Any idea how to cope with it?

Comment: D drive is NTFS, it doesn't work on C either.

Comment: Ha! 4.03 version does the job, it's working fine now. Thank you for you help!